# Combine 2 integer's text not add them together

Tags: c#, int

I have two integers, x and y. What I am trying to do, is combine the numbers in both, not add them together. I have tried to do this:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 10;
sum = x + y;
```

But that makes the output 15. 
What I am wondering is if there is any way to combine them, so that the output would be 510.

> 5 + 10 = 510

That is what I am trying to accomplice.

I know I could do something like this:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 10;
int sum;
sum = Convert.ToInt32(x.ToString() + y.ToString());
```

But that seems like a sloppy way to do it. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to concatenate strings, so concatenate strings.

Comment: AFAIK that's the shortest way to achieve it. You could use some maths to do it, but it will be longer.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy How do you do that?

Comment: @Dozer789 stringA + stringB

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I'm using a int though...

Comment: @Dozer789 you're already doing it, you called it sloppy

Comment: @Dozer789 where that int comes from? And why you need to concatenate these values as strings?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A little simplier:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 10;
int sum;
sum = Convert.ToInt32("" + x + y);
```

Notice that you need convertion in any case. [Implicit conversion](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/177153/Type-conversions-with-implicit-and-explicit-operat) is used here.

Comment: Brilliant! Just what I wanted! I would upvote, but my daily limit is reached. I'll upvote tomorrow!

Comment: Thanks for the article to CodeProject! Great article!

Comment: If it would be a method with params int[] and a linq statement I would up vote it. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
int x = 5;
int y = 11;

var z = (int)(x * Math.Pow(10, (int)Math.Log10(y) + 1) + y);
```

Comment: I like the math but is this really more simple?

Comment: @Harrison I didn't say that. Just without string ops.

Comment: As I said, you can use maths, but not only the answer is longer but the intent is clearly lost...

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is with strings since you are treating these as strings already:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 10;
string value = string.Format("{0}{1}", x, y);
sum = int.Parse(value);
```

That makes the output 510, and it is a little cleaner than your "sloppy way to do it".

Comment: Even shorter `var value = $"{x}{y}";`

Comment: @Neil, I started to put that, but being a 10 year old question, I put the output in 10 year old C#. :)

Comment: A 10 year old question that just appeared at the top of the C# questions.  Is SO having a senior moment :-)